# transferring wordpress blog posts from one blog to other including images

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I want to move all the blog posts from one wordpress installation to other, I know about the Import/Export option but that does not transfer images, I need to transfer the images.

Please ideas would be helpful

Comment: If you want to move your whole site to another host, I have answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245995/built-a-site-locally-on-wordpress-how-do-i-transfer-to-the-web-host/18248158#18248158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer from the Wordpress Forum outlines a good way to do this:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/migrating-blog-images-to-brand-new-wordpress-site-database

In short, all of your images live in wp-content/uploads. You'll need to combine the uploads folder from your old installation with the uploads folder in the new one, and then change the image URLs within the posts themselves.

It's a bit of a pain, and definitely would be a nice-to-have for them to include images in future versions of the import/export function.